# Multiple UIViews backed by OpenGLES

Tags: ios, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

In my app I am rendering live video frames from the camera and also using UIKit for laying out button controls. I would also like to display some real time data rendered in a smaller UIView. The thing is how do I use OpenGLES to render two different views on the same window? I looked at GPUImage but it blends all the views together to display multiple data, example video feed and histogram which I don't want.

Comment: Must it be two different views? Even AAA games use one view... you can mirror it in OpenGL

Comment: Well let's look at it like this. You have one main GL view that is full screen and shows camera frames. Then you have a number of transparent UI elements that are on top of this GL view. And one of these UI elements has transparent background and you need to have second GL view on this that shows histogram. How do you do it using just one GL view?

Comment: Have you developed any game using opengl? You can even make your own UI elements like UIView, UITableView, UIButton and so on. You can make many FBOs and use each fbo as if it is a view.